# Alternative to NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

I have two tables linked by an ID column. Let's call them Table A and table B. My goal is to find all the records in table A that have no record in table B. For instance:

```
**Table A:**  
ID    Value  
--    -------
1     value1  
2     value2  
3     value3  
4     value4

**Table B**  
ID    Value  
--    -------
1     x  
2     y  
4     z  
4     l
```

As you can see, record with ID = 3 does not exist in table B, so I want a query that will give me record 3 from table A. The way I am currently doing this is by saying `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM TableB where TableB.ID = TableA.ID)`, but since the tables are huge, the performance on this is terrible. Also, when I tried using a Left Join where TableB.ID is null, it didn't work. Can anyone suggest an alternative?

Comment: Do you mean, AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM TABLE B WHERE ID = tbla.ID) ?

Comment: @nitro yes i did, thanks for the correction

Comment: @sam, read the last sentence, already tried it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Not IN`

```
AND tablea.id NOT In (SELECT ID FROM TableB)
```

check more http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/Select-Query/NOTIN.htm

Comment: Better hope that ID column never has a NULL in it on TableB. Note that NOT IN and NOT EXISTS, if both columns are `NOT NULL`, should be *equivalent* in SQL server. For more info see here: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Answer (score 4):

You can replace it with

```
SELECT 
  a.ID, 
  a.Value
FROM Table_A AS a
LEFT JOIN Table_B AS b ON a.ID = b.ID     
WHERE b.ID IS NULL
```

This solution should be more efficient than `IN()` and `EXISTS()` alternatives. Source [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID 
  FROM Table_A
EXCEPT
SELECT ID 
  FROM Table_B;
```